# signalR and groups in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, signalr

I'm trying to finish my course work. The last thing that I cant finish is to realise chat groups. I read the wiki of signalR and also downloaded different examples how people realise chat groups. But in my project it doesn't work. Now I will try to explain how my project is working.

On main page I'm adding chat groups to list which also added and store in database:

```
public ActionResult Index(ChatUser model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (DataBaseClassDataContext dc = new DataBaseClassDataContext())
                {
                    Room room = new Room();
                    model.chatGroup = new List<string>(); 
                    model.chatGroup.Add(model.nameOfGroup);
                    var query = (
                        from u in dc.Users
                        from r in dc.Room
                        select new
                        {
                            u.ID
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
                    model.authorID = query.ID;
                    room.AuthorID = model.authorID;
                    room.Name = model.nameOfGroup;
                    dc.Room.InsertOnSubmit(room);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                } 
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

On next page, i'm displaing all groups which is stored in database and on click it redirect me to chat:

```
public ActionResult Rooms()
{
    return View(getRooms());
}

public List<Room> getRooms() {
    using (DataBaseClassDataContext dc = new DataBaseClassDataContext()) { 
    var query =
        (from q in dc.Room
             select q).ToList();
        return query;
    }
}
```

And cshtml:

```
@model List<Room>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rooms";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Chat", "Home")<br />
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

Strange thing that it duplicate message Wherever I been. in groups. 
Here chathub:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private static readonly List<ChatUser> ConnectedUsers = new List<ChatUser>();

        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatUser> chatUsers
            = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChatUser>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        public void Send(string message)
        {

            string sender = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            // So, broadcast the sender, too.
            Clients.All.received(new { sender = sender, message = message, isPrivate = false });
        }

        public void Send(string message, string to)
        {

            ChatUser receiver;
            if (chatUsers.TryGetValue(to, out receiver))
            {

                ChatUser sender = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);

                IEnumerable<string> allReceivers;
                lock (receiver.ConnectionIds)
                {
                    lock (sender.ConnectionIds)
                    {

                        allReceivers = receiver.ConnectionIds.Concat(sender.ConnectionIds);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var cid in allReceivers)
                {
                    Clients.Client(cid).received(new { sender = sender.userLogin, message = message, isPrivate = true });
                }
            }
        }

        public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
            SendGroupMessage(user, message);
        }

        private void SendGroupMessage(ChatUser user, string message)
        {
            Clients.Group(user.CurrentGroup).addMessage(user.userLogin, message);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetConnectedUsers()
        {

            return chatUsers.Where(x =>
            {

                lock (x.Value.ConnectionIds)
                {

                    return !x.Value.ConnectionIds.Contains(Context.ConnectionId, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }

            }).Select(x => x.Key);
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {

            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            var user = chatUsers.GetOrAdd(userName, _ => new ChatUser
            {
                userLogin = userName,
                ConnectionIds = new HashSet<string>()
            });

            lock (user.ConnectionIds)
            {

                user.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);

                //Add to default group
                //await 
                //Groups.Add(user.ConnectionIds, user.CurrentGroup);
                string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();

                Groups.Add(connectionGrpToString, user.CurrentGroup);

                UpdateGroupUserList(user.CurrentGroup);

                var message = string.Format("{0} has joined.", user.userLogin);
                SendGroupAlert(user, message);

                var personalMessage = string.Format("You have joined {0} as {1}.", user.CurrentGroup, user.userLogin);
                SendPersonalAlert(personalMessage);
                // // broadcast this to all clients other than the caller
                // Clients.AllExcept(user.ConnectionIds.ToArray()).userConnected(userName);

                // Or you might want to only broadcast this info if this 
                // is the first connection of the user
                if (user.ConnectionIds.Count == 1)
                {

                    Clients.Others.userConnected(userName);
                }
            }

            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
        {
            var user = GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
            ChatUser group = new ChatUser(); ;
            string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();
            if (!group.chatGroup.Contains(groupName))
            {
                SendPersonalAlert("No group exists by that name");
                return;
            }
            if (user.CurrentGroup.Equals(groupName))
            {
                SendPersonalAlert("You are already a member of that group");
                return;
            }

            //Remove from current group
            var oldGroup = user.CurrentGroup;

            //Tell everyone user is leaving
            var message = string.Format("{0} has left.", user.userLogin);
            SendGroupAlert(user, message);

            //remove user from the group
            //await 
            Groups.Remove(connectionGrpToString, oldGroup);

            //Join new Group
            user.CurrentGroup = groupName;
            //await 
            Groups.Add(connectionGrpToString, user.CurrentGroup);

            //Update the user lists for the old and new group
            UpdateGroupUserList(oldGroup);
            UpdateGroupUserList(user.CurrentGroup);

            message = string.Format("{0} has joined.", user.userLogin);
            SendGroupAlert(user, message);

            message = string.Format("You have joined {0}", user.CurrentGroup);
            SendPersonalAlert(message);
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {

            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            ChatUser user;
            chatUsers.TryGetValue(userName, out user);

            if (user != null)
            {

                lock (user.ConnectionIds)
                {

                    user.ConnectionIds.RemoveWhere(cid => cid.Equals(connectionId));

                    if (!user.ConnectionIds.Any())
                    {

                        ChatUser removedUser;
                        chatUsers.TryRemove(userName, out removedUser);

                        UpdateGroupUserList(user.CurrentGroup);

                        //Alert that user left
                        var message = string.Format("{0} has left.", user.userLogin);
                        SendGroupAlert(user, message);

                        // You might want to only broadcast this info if this 
                        // is the last connection of the user and the user actual is 
                        // now disconnected from all connections.
                        Clients.Others.userDisconnected(userName);
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }

        private ChatUser GetUser(string username)
        {

            ChatUser user;
            chatUsers.TryGetValue(username, out user);

            return user;
        }

        private List<ChatUser> GetUsersByGroup(string groupName)
        {
            return ConnectedUsers.Where(x => x.CurrentGroup == groupName).ToList();
        }

        private void UpdateGroupUserList(string group)
        {
            var users = GetUsersByGroup(group);
            Clients.Group(group).refreshUserList(users);
        }

        private void SendGroupAlert(ChatUser user, string message)
        {
            string connectionGrpToString = user.ConnectionIds.ToString();
            Clients.Group(user.CurrentGroup, connectionGrpToString).systemAlert(message);
        }

        private void SendPersonalAlert(string message)
        {
            Clients.Caller.systemAlert(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Here chat.js knockout:

```
(function () {

    function Message(from, msg, isPrivate) {
        this.from = ko.observable(from);
        this.message = ko.observable(msg);
        this.isPrivate = ko.observable(isPrivate);
    }

    function User(name) {

        var self = this;

        self.name = ko.observable(name);
        self.isPrivateChatUser = ko.observable(false);
        self.setAsPrivateChat = function (user) {
            viewModel.privateChatUser(user.name());
            viewModel.isInPrivateChat(true);
            $.each(viewModel.users(), function (i, user) {
                user.isPrivateChatUser(false);
            });
            self.isPrivateChatUser(true);
        };
    }

    var viewModel = {
        messages: ko.observableArray([]),
        users: ko.observableArray([]),
        isInPrivateChat: ko.observable(false),
        privateChatUser: ko.observable(),
        exitFromPrivateChat: function () {

            viewModel.isInPrivateChat(false);
            viewModel.privateChatUser(null);
            $.each(viewModel.users(), function (i, user) {
                user.isPrivateChatUser(false);
            });
        }
    };

    $(function () {

        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub,
            loginHub = $.connection.login,
            $sendBtn = $('#btnSend'),
            $msgTxt = $('#txtMsg');

        // turn the logging on for demo purposes
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        chatHub.client.received = function (message) {
            viewModel.messages.push(new Message(message.sender, message.message, message.isPrivate));
        };

        chatHub.client.userConnected = function (username) {
            viewModel.users.push(new User(username));
        };

        chatHub.client.userDisconnected = function (username) {
            viewModel.users.pop(new User(username));
            if (viewModel.isInPrivateChat() && viewModel.privateChatUser() === username) {
                viewModel.isInPrivateChat(false);
                viewModel.privateChatUser(null);
            }
        };

        startConnection();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        function startConnection() {

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

                toggleInputs(false);
                bindClickEvents();

                $msgTxt.focus();

                chatHub.server.getConnectedUsers().done(function (users) {
                    $.each(users, function (i, username) {
                        viewModel.users.push(new User(username));
                    });
                });

            }).fail(function (err) {

                console.log(err);
            });
        }

        function bindClickEvents() {

            $msgTxt.keypress(function (e) {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                if (code === 13) {
                    sendMessage();
                }
            });

            $sendBtn.click(function (e) {

                sendMessage();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }

        function sendMessage() {

            var msgValue = $msgTxt.val();
            if (msgValue !== null && msgValue.length > 0) {

                if (viewModel.isInPrivateChat()) {

                    chatHub.server.send(msgValue, viewModel.privateChatUser()).fail(function (err) {
                        console.log('Send method failed: ' + err);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    chatHub.server.send(msgValue).fail(function (err) {
                        console.log('Send method failed: ' + err);
                    });
                }
            }

            $msgTxt.val(null);
            $msgTxt.focus();
        }

        function toggleInputs(status) {

            $sendBtn.prop('disabled', status);
            $msgTxt.prop('disabled', status);
        }
    });
}());
```

And chat models:

```
public class ChatUser
{
    public ChatUser(string group)
    {
        CurrentGroup = group;
    }

    public ChatUser()
        : this("Lobby")
    {

    }

    public string nameOfGroup { get; set; }
    public int authorID { get; set; }

    public List<string> chatGroup { get; set; }
    public string CurrentGroup { get; set; }

    public string userLogin { get; set; }
    public HashSet<string> ConnectionIds { get; set; }
}
```

I apologize for big part of code, I just do not know where there may be a mistake, because I newbie in asp.net mvc.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Can you explain some test case?

Comment: I mean, when I join a different room via tabs and write different messages in different tabs, it is displayed as if I'm in the same room and all the message that I wrote with different rooms have been shown everywhere.

Comment: It seems right behavior as you are removing user from old group (room) as he joins a new one. So when you join a new room in the other tab you will be removed from the room in the first tab. Check your JoinGroup code. `//Remove from current group var oldGroup = user.CurrentGroup;  //Tell everyone user is leaving  var message = string.Format("{0} has left.", user.userLogin);
            SendGroupAlert(user, message);

            //remove user from the group
            //await 
            Groups.Remove(connectionGrpToString, oldGroup);
`

Comment: Yesterday i tried to rework code of chathub.cs, i've found one thing that i didnt send message via `Clients.Group(user.CurrentGroup).addMessage(user.userLogin, message)` and didn't work, but it's work with `Clients.All.received(new { sender = sender, message = message, isPrivate = false });` Now i'm trying to find solution of this.